# Why would a bat file that just starts a program be considered a virus?

Tags: virus, antivirus, trojan, batch

My friend's computer was having a lot of viruses so he wanted me to download an operating system for him. So he gave me a flash memory. When I opened the flash my antivirus (Kaspersky Total Security) kept removing it saying it was `Trojan.bat.runner.bv`. I have restored it a lot of times but it kept deleting it. So I renamed it from `1.bat` to `1.txt` and all I found was this:

```
cd .Trashes
start wscript "459\vrdve.js"
exit
```

My question is how is that a virus? It won't harm my computer in any way it just starts a program.

Comment: was 459\vrdve.js on the drive, too?

Comment: nope but i think it was on my friend's computer

Comment: sounds like it's a trojan, not a virus.

Comment: "It won't harm my computer in any way it just starts a program." Malware are programs too, malicious ones, but programs after all

Answer (score 3):

It would be detected as a virus because it is an executable (.bat) calling a Javascript file. A recipe for a bad infection.

Comment: And by the way, running Javascript with Windows Script Host (wscript) is far more dangerous than running it in a web browser. The Javascript API available in the WSH can do pretty much anything on the system.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the content of `459\vrdve.js`. If the file is a benign file, it may be a false alarm. Check if there is a `459` subdirectory on the flash drive. If there is, immediately use the Windows Security options to add a "Deny" entry of Execute file/Traverse directory and inspect the `459/vrdve.js` file as a `txt` file. Post the code here.